# LibreOffice Impress to S5

Tags: html, presentations, libreoffice-impress

Is it possible to convert LibreOffice Impress presentation to [S5](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/) (Simple Standards-Based Slide Show System)? Is there a pluging for LibreOffice or a command-line tool?

Currently LibreOffice can export to HTML, but it makes every slide a png-image, meaning that text also becomes part of the image.